# How to convert mysql to laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

Hi all i have this raw query in mysql i need to translate to laravel 5.4 query builder

```
select * from pages where (phase_id, type) in (select max(phase_id),type from pages where phase_id<=2 and actived=1 group by type) and actived=1
```

i don't know how to convert in query builder where clausule with 2 colum

any ideas?

Thx all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$results = DB::select(
    select * from pages where (phase_id, type) 
    in (
        select max(phase_id), type 
        from pages 
        where phase_id <= 2 
        and actived = 1 
        group by type
    ) 
    and actived = 1
);
```

Comment: Thx @EddyTheDove ;) exists another way using ->whare() or whareIn() method of query builder?

Comment: if you have an array of IDs, yes you can use whereIn. But it doesnt take SQL like that. You must pass it an array.