# SQL query to Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I am trying to convert the following query to Laravel:

```
select libéllé
from application 
where libéllé not in (select application_id from application_user 
where user_id = $id)
```

Comment: docs will help you https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#selects

Comment: May we see your attempt, Wahib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel `whereNotIn` supports closures for subqueries, so it will be as simple as this:

Using Eloquent:

```
// Add this to top of your file.
use App\{ Application, ApplicationUser };

// Get your entries.
$rows = Application::whereNotIn('libéllè', function($query) use ($id) {
    $query->select('application_id')->from((new ApplicationUser)->getTable())->where('user_id', $id);
})->get(['libéllè']);
```

Using Query Builder:

```
$rows = DB::table('application')->whereNotIn('libéllè', function($query) use ($id) {
    $query->select('application_id')->from('application_user')->where('user_id', $id);
})->get(['libéllè']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try it.

```
$results = DB::select(
    select libéllé
from application 
where (libéllé)
 not in(
        select application_id from application_user     
     where user_id = $id
    ) 
);
```

Also see this answer: [How to convert mysql to laravel query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574418/how-to-convert-mysql-to-laravel-query-builder)

Also see this documentation: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel5-resolve-username-from-2-tables?page=1